# Create in memory test with system.Web.Http.HttpServer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, integration-testing, httpserver

I would like to ask if it possible to wire up a full mvc/api (v5.2.3) site with the in memory HttpServer.

I am using owin and need to wire it up.

If it going to work I need to call static Startup() and Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in class Startup.cs in my integration test.

I read the article [ASP.NET Web API integration testing with in-memory hosting](https://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/asp-net-web-api-integration-testing-with-in-memory-hosting/) it gave me a deeper understanding of the HttpServer, - but as always close but no cigar.

Can it be done?

Comment: Take a look a the answer I provided here that references the same article https://stackoverflow.com/a/37510032/5233410

Comment: Here is another one that may prove useful https://stackoverflow.com/q/40423823/5233410

Comment: This question can be easily be answered with a "Yes, it can." Now, is that enough, or do you want to clarify the actual problem you have run into that you need help to solve?

Comment: I would very much like to see an example on how to wire it all up in a unit test

Comment: Have a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49202654/2928038